# How to make iOS believe there is Internet Connectivity

Tags: ipad

I am working on a web application for iOS that is going to be accesed from a local webserver in a network that has NO internet connectivity at all.

My problem is that everytime an iOS device is locked, it disconnects from the WiFi network, so when the device is unlocked again, it has to reconnect. Part of that reconnection process is determining if there is Internet connection (which there isn't). Until the process is not finished iOS does not allow any DNS resolution (so if I write http://10.0.0.1 it will go there, but not if I request http://something.local.com).

Since we control that network, we want to know how to does iOS verifies Internet connectivity so that we can fake the responses it expects.

Comment: Since this question can not be answered by code or the use of coding tools, I would assume it to be off-topic and better asked at server fault.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to resolve DNS without an internet connection on iOS, but if that's the case, that would be a way better solution since you don't need to mess with your router settings. Use my solution only if it really isn't possible with only code.
I'll suggest you to follow this guide: http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/06/sniff-your-iphones-network-traffic to check which actions your iPhone executes to detect an internet connection.
Using this information you could forward the is-there-internet-requests on your router to a local server which fakes the there-is-internet-responses.
This assumes Apple really uses an external server to detect this, which I'm not sure about. But it wouldn't hurt to give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Reachability Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_5)? You don't have to use the `reachabilityForInternetConnection` method, which checks if a default route is available. You can use the `reachabilityWithAddress:` method and check if your server is reachable.